# Serilog.Sinks.Email - No Indication of Failure?

Tags: serilog

I've been working with Serilog.Sinks.Email, and I notice that (other than the fact that I don't get an email), there is no exception or anything that indicates a failure when I execute the Log statement.  Even if I put in junk for the MailServer, the Log statement executes as though it were successful.

I've tried the SelfLog statement, but see nothing in my Output window from that.

```
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg));
```

I've added SymbolSource (http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Wiki/Using), and am able to step through Serilog's code, but once again, no exceptions are caught.

Does Serilog really give no indication of error, or am I missing something?

Using: .NET Framework 4.6.2, Serilog 2.8, Serilog.Sinks.Email 2.3

Sample Code:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Email(new EmailConnectionInfo
    {
        FromEmail = "xxx",
        ToEmail = "xxx",
        MailServer = "smtp.xxx.com",
        EmailSubject = "My Test"
    }
    ).CreateLogger();

Log.ForContext<Program>().Error("Test Number {Parm}", "1");
```

Comment: I am not going to check right now, but I'd be very surprised if `xxx.com` wasn't a registered domain :)

Comment: Ha, nice catch!  The xxx's are replacing actual values in my code :).  The actual junk value I tried was "unknown" or "nonexistent" for the whole MailServer value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Writing to a Serilog logger is supposed to be a safe operation and never throw exceptions, [by design](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Reliability), thus any exceptions that happen when sending the e-mail would only appear in the `SelfLog` - in your case, it would write to the `Debug` console.

Now, the reason you're not even seeing exceptions in the `SelfLog` is because e-mails sent via [`Serilog.Sinks.Email`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-email) are sent [asynchronously](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-email/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.Email/Sinks/Email/EmailSink.cs#L139), and your program is terminating before the the Sink had the opportunity to send the e-mail.

Before your program terminates, you need to call `Log.CloseAndFlush()` so that all logs can be sent, before the app closes.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Console.WriteLine(msg));

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.Email(...)
        .CreateLogger();

    try
    {
        Log.ForContext<Program>().Error("Test Number {Parm}", "1");

        // ...
    }
    finally
    {
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }
}
```

That will allow you to see the error messages you're writing via `SelfLog`.

You can read more about that in the documentation: [Lifecycle of Loggers](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Lifecycle-of-Loggers).

---

ps: If the operation you're logging is important enough that you'd want to guarantee it succeeds (or throw exception if it doesn't) then you should use [Audit Logging](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/10/october-serilog-update/), i.e. Use `.AuditTo.Email(...)` instead of `.WriteTo.Email(...)`

Comment: Thanks for that info!  However, after adding that, still no error is caught, even if using a junk MailServer value or incorrect credentials.

Comment: @JamesinIndy Maybe you are not looking in the output window? In the example above, you configured `SelfLog` to write to the `Debug`... https://i.imgur.com/sFrxb8a.png

Comment: Aha, now that I've added CloseAndFlush(), I see my SelfLog errors in the Output window after that statement executes.  I find it odd that it doesn't hit a Catch statement--then again, what would I do if I caught it?  I'm already trying to log an error, so if that failed, logging the log's failure would likely fail too.

Comment: @JamesinIndy [That is by design](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Reliability). Writing to a Serilog logger is supposed to be a safe operation and never throw exceptions. If the operation you're logging is important enough that you'd want to guarantee it succeeds (or throw exception if it doesn't) then you should use [Audit Logging](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Reliability), i.e. Use `.AuditTo.Email(...)` instead of `.WriteTo.Email(...)`...